# Setting and EmberJS models owner with a simple ID

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have code that tries to set the owner of a model instance by simply setting the id of the owner as follows:

```
tableJSON = {id: 1, room_id: 1}

rec = App.Table.createRecord();
rec.setProperties(tableJSON);
App.store.commit();
```

I am using the `localStorage ember adapter`.

It does not set the room on the table model.
The model specifies that table belongs to room.

when I call `table.get('room')`, it returns null.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you giving your instance of `App.Room` an id and a room_id? shouldn't it rather get an owner_id?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the code I posted. I have fixed it there. The Table model has `room: DS.belongsTo 'App.Room'`

Comment: hmm, have you already tried using "room" instead of "room_id", then? that's how it works with fixtures, at least. also, just to make sure, have you seen to it that a room with id 1 exists?

Comment: I have just done a good bit of testing in the javascript console and it seems that it does not work for either specifying room or room_id as an attribute. I can also verify that there is a room object with id of 1. Could it be a bug in the localStorage adapter?